# Do Acyl Carrier Proteins and Conenzyme A have similar reactivity?

Tags: biochemistry

In terms of the reactions they undergo are they roughly equivalent groups?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The acyl groups ligated to CoA and to acyl carrier proteins are actually attached to the same group (a phosphopantetheine group) as shown below, and so have very similar reactivities (i.e. group transfer potentials).

[image]